# Inconsistance spacing in numpy array elements

Tags: python, numpy

In python when I say **np.array([1,2,3])**, the result is

```
array([1, 2, 3])
```

but when I say **np.array([11,22,3])** the result is

```
array([11, 22,  3])
```

which has two spaces before '3' unlike '22' which has one space before.  Later i am using map function to read this result from a CSV file with Pandas

```
appended_data.append({'array': numpyarray})
OutputDataFrame = pd.DataFrame(appended_data).ix[:, columns]
OutputDataFrame.to_csv('name.csv', index=False)
```

and i need the spacing to be consistent. is there any way to do so ?

Comment: How are you saving it to CSV?  You shouldn't be saving that format to CSV.  Save the data to CSV, not the display form.

Comment: Is the CSV really spaced the same way the `repr` of the numpy array is? This seems like either a non-issue (a concern that isn't actually a real problem) or you're doing something very odd with your numpy array that preserves the space from its `repr`.

Comment: [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) writes in the standard, compressed CSV format by default. So, `array([11, 22,  3])` without headers will be written as `11,22,3`. This is a non-issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the evenly spaced numpy array to a list first:

```
np.array([11, 22,  3]).tolist()
```

will give you

```
[11, 22, 3]
```

Also, when you map the numpy array, each individual value passed to the function will not have spacing so you don't have to worry about it.

*See [hpaulj's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41657078/inconsistance-spacing-in-numpy-array-elements/41657855#41657855) as it's much more comprehensive than mine.*

Comment: Recommending `list(array...)` is not good practice.  `array.tolist()` is a more reliable way of converting an array to a list.  The result is the same with a 1d array, but try it with 2d.  And I don't see how this helps when interacting with pandas.

Answer (score 5):

The default display for arrays is a uniform field width per element, not a uniform spacing:

```
In [30]: x=np.array([11,223,3])

In [31]: x
Out[31]: array([ 11, 223,   3])

In [32]: x.tolist()      # list display with uniform spacing
Out[32]: [11, 223, 3]
```

In effect `numpy` uses a format like:

```
In [35]: fmt = '  '.join(['%3d','%3d','%3d'])

In [36]: fmt
Out[36]: '%3d  %3d  %3d'

In [37]: fmt%tuple(x)
Out[37]: ' 11  223    3'
```

`np.savetxt` does just that, using the `fmt` and `delimiter` that you provide.

`csv` stands for 'comma separated'.  Tabs are also used.  If 'white space' is used, good readers are just as happy with one, two or more 'blanks'.  Such tables are usually formatted to keep the columns aligned, not to keep the space between numbers constant.

A 3 row array with mixed number sizes:

```
In [39]: x=np.array([[1,123,32],[34,1,2],[0,23,1000]])

In [40]: x
Out[40]: 
array([[   1,  123,   32],
       [  34,    1,    2],
       [   0,   23, 1000]])
```

Fixed width csv formatting:

```
In [41]: np.savetxt('test.csv',x,fmt='%5d', delimiter=',')

In [42]: cat test.csv
    1,  123,   32
   34,    1,    2
    0,   23, 1000
```

delimited reading:

```
In [43]: np.genfromtxt('test.csv',delimiter=',',dtype=None)
Out[43]: 
array([[   1,  123,   32],
       [  34,    1,    2],
       [   0,   23, 1000]])
```

The default mode for Python string split uses generalized white space:

```
In [44]: ' 11  223    3'.split()
Out[44]: ['11', '223', '3']
```

Here's an example of a csv with constant spacing (and variable width)

```
In [45]: np.savetxt('test.csv',x,fmt='%d', delimiter=' ')

In [46]: cat test.csv
1 123 32
34 1 2
0 23 1000
```

`np.genfromtxt('test.csv',dtype=None)` reads it just fine.